# variation of a smooth function on a curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, curves, line-integrals

Assume $f$ is a smooth (e.g. $C^1$) real-valued function defined on a domain $\Delta\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $t\in[a,b]\to\gamma(t)$ be a smooth curve in $\Delta$ with endpoints $x=\gamma(a)$ and $y=\gamma(b)$. Then,
$$f(y)-f(x)=\int_a^b\nabla f(\gamma(t))\cdot\gamma'(t)dt,$$
from which follows, together with Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, that
$$|f(y)-f(x)|\leq\sup_{s\in\gamma}\|\nabla f(s)\|_2\cdot\text{length}(\gamma).
$$
**Question** : Does this inequality still hold true if we only assume the curve $\gamma$ to be rectifiable ?

Any reference would be appreciated, Thanks !

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $||\nabla f(s)||_2$?

Comment: @Thomas The $L^2$ norm of the gradient of $f$.

Comment: As an integral norm? And this depends on $s$?

Comment: @Thomas Apply C-S to the scalar product, then take out of the integral the sup of $\|\nabla f\|_2$. The remaining integral is the length of $\gamma$.

Comment: If you choose a Lipschitz parametrization, the same proof goes through (using the version of the fundamental theorem of calculus for absolutely continuous functions).

Comment: I see, thank you very much !